# Unable to read dates in proper format using read.xlsx Package in R

Tags: r, excel, readxl

[image]Hey all! I have been trying to read some data into R from an Excel file using the read.xlsx() function. I have dates ranging from the year 1843. I have tried the various tips available online but not been able to get the proper date format. If anyone could provide any suggestions it would be a big help. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Import the dates as text, then use `as.POSIXct()` to transfer to the right format.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for that but the date column gets read in as a factor. I am finding it hard to find a way on how to proceed. Any idea on what do I do?

Comment: I have good experiences with the readxl-package.

Answer (score 0):

```
df <- tibble(
  DOB = c(19644, 29571, 19744, 22557, 28258, 24366)
)



df_2 <- df %>%
mutate(DOB = DOB %>% 
       as.character %>%     # First convert the factors into character strings
       as.numeric %>%       # ...and then to numeric days since origin
       as.Date(origin = "1899-12-30")  # ...and finally to a date
     )
# Note: for Excel on Mac, the origin is "1904-01-01" because Think Different.
```